# Unwrapping optional in SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I try to unwrap my optional property, but get this Error message:

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'

I don't see whats wrong with my code

```
HStack {
    if let height = profile.height {
        TagBox(field: "height", value: String(height))
    }
    TagBox(field: "nationality", value: profile.nationality)
    Spacer()
}.padding(.horizontal)
```

Comment: “I don't see whats wrong with my code”    The very first word is wrong. You cannot say `HStack { if let`. These curly braces cannot contain executable code. All they can contain is views.

Comment: It doesn’t matter. You cannot say `if let` there at all.

Comment: How do I do it then? Where to unwrap?

Comment: I do not know what problem you are trying to solve. You have shown no context. What is profile? What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is: if the "profile.height" is given (which is an optional), then show me the TagBox(..), which is wrapped inside the braces.

Comment: What is a profile? What is a tag box?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to work with optionals in this context:

The first one, if you don't want this view to show at all if profile.height is nil:

```
profile.height.map({ TagBox(field: "height", value: String($0))})
```

The second one, if you want this view to show, but with a default value instead:

```
TagBox(field: "height", value: String(profile.height ?? 0))
```

Comment: but the problem here on soloution 2 is: The TagBox has background color and other stuff. So if I pass the 0 instead. There will be a blank blue container. I tried to think of doing a if statement in the TagBox View, but I don't know how I can return a void, or nothing at all.

Comment: The first case caters for a scenario when you don't want this view at all if the value is nil. Use map and if height is nil the view won't get initialized. I do don't quite understand your objections.

Comment: what if the desired value is data and we use Image what can you advice? I have data model where I store Data? property but it's optional, how to unwrap then? thanks!

Comment: Hi @MatrosovAlexander, could you post it as a separate question please? It's a bit too much typing for a comment. Thanks

Comment: Hi @LuLuGaGa, yea I posted it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61332124/swiftui-unwrap-optional-image-data-to-create-image-based-on-uiimagedata/61335865#61335865) thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 5.3 - Xcode 12

Using conditional binding in a `ViewBuilder` is perfectly fine now:

```
HStack {
    if let height = profile.height { // <- This works now in Xcode 12
        TagBox(field: "height", value: String(height))
    }
    TagBox(field: "nationality", value: profile.nationality)
    Spacer()
}.padding(.horizontal)
```

Answer (score 3):

So if the force unwrap makes you feel uneasy you can use the following custom view I made up:

```
struct OptionalView<Value, Content>: View where Content: View {
    private var content: Content

    init?(_ value: Value?, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Value) -> Content) {
        guard let value = value else { return nil }
        self.content = content(value)
    }

    var body: some View {
        content
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
OptionalView(profile.height) { height in
    TagBox(field: "height", value: String(height))
}
```

I wrote a post about this and making a chain of optional views [here](https://medium.com/@garsdle/unwrapping-optionals-in-swiftui-7563dcc200e7)

Comment:   https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/optional-swiftui-views/

Answer (score 2):

You can have if statements inside of a `Group`'s view builder. I made an example to illustrate:

```
var label1 = "label 1"
@State var label2: String?
var label3: String? = "label 3"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(label1)
        Group {
            if label2 != nil {
                Text(label2!)
            }
            if label3 != nil {
                Text(label3!)
            }
        }
        Button(action: {
            self.label2 = "Button pressed!"
        }) {
            Text("Press me!")
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, in this example, you could just do `Text(label2 ?? "")`, but there would be a gap where the `Text` is until `label2` has a value, and also, in more complex situations, this allows for more flexibility. If you run that code, you will see "Label 1" directly above "Label 3", and if you press the button, "Button pressed!" will appear in between "Label 1" and "Label 3".

Basically, if `label2` is nil, there won't be a blank space where the label will be when it has a value, instead there will be no gap, and when `label2` is assigned a value, everything above and below where it should be will shift to accommodate for it.

In the code you provided, you can change it to:

```
HStack {
    Group {
        if profile.height != nil {
            TagBox(field: "height", value: String(profile.height!))
        }
    }
    TagBox(field: "nationality", value: profile.nationality)
    Spacer()
}.padding(.horizontal)
```

The nice thing about this solution is that you can do more complex things in the scenario that the value is nil (or not), and even provide a default view in case the value is nil (In my example, this would be the equivalent of adding an `else` 
for either `if` statement with a `Button`, `Text`, etc. inside of the `else`'s body).

One drawback is that you have to explicitly unwrap the optionals, which shouldn't be a problem because the if statement takes care of making sure it is not nil, but I still find that optional binding is generally a cleaner route for unwrapping optionals.

**Edit**:

If you really don't want to explicitly unwrap optionals, you can use `ViewBuilder`s:

```
var label1 = "label 1"
@State var label2: String?
var label3: String? = "label 3"
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(label1)
        Group {
            self.conditionalText(self.label2)
            if label3 != nil {
                Text(label3!)
            }
        }
        Button(action: {
            self.label2 = "Button pressed!"
        }) {
            Text("Press me!")
        }
    }
}
func conditionalText(_ text: String?) -> some View {
    if let text = text {
        return ViewBuilder.buildIf(Text(text))
    } else {
        print("Text is nil")
    }
    let view: Text? = nil
    return ViewBuilder.buildIf(view)
}
```

This method also highlights how you can have executable code inside of a `Group` as long as it is inside of a function that returns a view.

Comment: I came to that soloution too, but I thought that would be a not so nice soloution, because you could use the unwrapping, which looks better to me. But thank you very much anyway

Comment: @seref The thing is to keep in mind what I said in my comment. You cannot perform executable code here! The `if` in a Group is not a normal `if`; it is a special dispensation that allows you show a view conditionally. So this is a good solution.

Comment: @matt you can actually perform executable code in kind of a work-around way - if you create a function that returns a view, and have executable code in that function, and then call that function in the if statement, everything should properly compile.

Comment: Personally I think this should be the accepted answer, because it explains why the _syntax_ of the original question fails and what to do about that.

Comment: See edit for an example of using a function for executable code in a Group and how you can use that to unwrap optionals the way that the OP did in their question post.