# SwiftUI - Unwrap optional image data to create Image based on UIImage(data)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368155/unwrapping-optional-in-view-swiftui) and some answer says that we can solve two tasks:

- Display view element if needed
- Or display default value instead if nil found

I have data model which contain optional `Data` properly which I use for my `Image` element on the `View`.

Currently as I have not found a way how to workaround this and use this sign `!` which is unsafe:

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: userService.user.imageData!)!)
```

For sure I can't guarantee it and I should not use this, but need a help how to unwrap this.

As a quick workaround I can make this image data property as non optional and then load some data from the local file, but even then I still have one more force unwrapping here `UIImage(data`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options available. I think the most straightforward is to make an extension on Image and define a new initialiser that will serve your needs:

```
extension Image {

    public init?(data: Data?) {
        guard let data = data,
            let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return nil
        }
        self = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```
Image(data: userService.user.imageData)
```

since it is `nullable` it needs to be contained in another `View` with at least one other `View`.

If you want to provide a placeholder in place of a missing image you could use an extension like this:

```
extension Image {

    public init(data: Data?, placeholder: String) {
        guard let data = data,
          let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
            self = Image(placeholder)
            return
        }
        self = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```
Image(data: userService.user.imageData, placeholder: "nameOfPlaceholder")
```

since it is not `nullable` it doe not need to be contained in another `View` with at least one other `View`.

Answer (score 6):

## Approach:

- Use control statements
- Use `AnyView` to erase type

## Reason for `AnyView`

- You need to erase the type so that your view consistently returns the same view type irrespective which execution path it takes (whether `if` statement is satisfied or not).
- That way it returns `AnyView` no matter what and will satisfy the body type (`some View`)

## Example:

- If the data is valid image data an image would be displayed
- If not then an empty view is displayed

**Note:** Instead of the empty view you could display any other view.

## Code:

```
import SwiftUI

class Model : ObservableObject {
    var data : Data?

    init(data: Data?) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model : Model

    var body: some View {

        let view : AnyView

        if let data = model.data,
            let uiimage = UIImage(data: data) {
            view = AnyView(Image(uiImage: uiimage))
        }
        else {
            view = AnyView(EmptyView()) //You could have view = AnyView(Text("no image found"))
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following variant is simple & safe (if you need to always have Image in view hierarchy), because `UIImage(data: Data())` always creates valid empty image.

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: userService.user.imageData ?? Data())!)
```

Comment: When I try to use `UIImage(data: Data())!` I get `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. This is in a WatchOS 8.5 app, Xcode 13.4

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return just an empty image, not a placeholder or another view, you can use the `CIImage.empty()`. The benefit is that the View hierarchy stays the same. In either case, the `Image` view is returned and the structural identity is kept. It may be important for UI-tests.

```
let uiImage: UIImage
if let imageData = userService.user.imageData,
   let image = UIImage(data: image) {
   uiImage = image
} else {
   uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: .empty())
}

return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
```